# dynamic javascript when using load->view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, local-storage

I have a form with a « newInput » button, which add dynamically in javascript a new input when I click to it.

When I have an error in my form, I re-load the view with the form. It’s normal, but .. Because I use dynamic javascript for adding new input, all the input added are removed when I reload..

There is something I can do ?

This is an exemple of my view.tpl :

```
<input 
  type="text"  
  placeholder="ex: cerise" 
  onfocus="javascript:autoComplet('jigd1', '{site_url('recettes/getIngredient')}')" 
  value="{set_value('igd[]')}" id="jigd1" name="igd[]"
/>
{form_error('igd[]')}
```

I add a partiel code of my js file

```
var cpt=1;
function addField(uriIngredient, uriLabel) {
try 
{
cpt=cpt+1;
var inputIgd = document.createElement('input'), 
button = document.createElement('input'),
div = document.createElement('div'),
inputIgd.setAttribute('type','text');
inputIgd.setAttribute('name','igd[]');
inputIgd.setAttribute('id','jigd'+cpt);


button.setAttribute('type','button');
button.setAttribute('onclick','javascript:supField("igd'+cpt+'")');
button.setAttribute('value','Supprimer');
div.setAttribute('id','igd'+cpt);
div.appendChild(inputIgd);
div.appendChild(button);
document.getElementById("listIgd").appendChild(div);
...
```

After some research, I tried to look at what someone said me, that's say **localStorage**, and it is very nice. **But** I used an exemple for only one input because i wrote it in my html, but I don't know how to do for recreate all inputs .. And particularly because I use javascript to add new inputs, I don't know if I can recreate all inputs .

Comment: You should consider submitting your form via ajax, and processing the response (displaying error messages, etc) using javascript.  That way you can avoid the issue of a page reload entirely

Comment: There is not another solution ?

Comment: There are many solutions, that's just the one I'd go with.  Another way to go would be to submit the page normally, and have your server return the updated html, with the dynamically added content

Comment: That's say Jonah ? How to do it ?

Comment: Implementing my last suggestion is a server side problem and is beyond the scope of your question or this site.

Answer (score 0):

check the form before submitting, that way you won't have to reload the page, for example using jquery ...

```
$("#myformid").on("submit", function(){
    var goodtogo = true;
    // some code here to check the form, if there's an error --> goodtogo = false;
    if (!goodtogo) return false; // and some other code to display the errors
});
```

That way, if there's an error , the form won't submit and won't reload.
If you have to check something in a database (for example) like checking if a username already exists, you'll have to use ajax.

Comment: I'm already checking my error with CodeIgniter form validation.. I really can't do without it..

Comment: well then, i suggest you use AJAX, it's really powerful and once you get used to it, you'll love it